# Setting up multiple test sites on a live server

Tags: iis-7, ssl

I have a offsite live server that I manage along with my colleagues where we host two sites for our business. We want to be able to also host the same sites but test versions on the same box.

The problem being experienced is that we want to set these sites up for testing from our office only and we do not want to provide host names for the test versions because we don't want Google to pick up on the test versions.

the other problemis that we have secure pages on these sites and when we set the test sites to be hosted on different ports to the live sites, when we try to visit a secure page on the test version sites the URL doesn't know which port number to include in the destination pages URL.

Sorry If I am unclear. Has anyone experienced any similar issues?

Comment: I have found a solution. Hopefully it may help others.

Basically on our local DNS server we have the address livestaging001 and livestaging002 pointing to the IP of our IIS7 web server hosted offsite. Then in IIS for our test site we have hosted it on port 80(same as out live websites) but given the binding the host name of livestaging002. This has both resolved the issue of not having to host multiple websites on different ports and also of our secure pages being redirected correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit your HOSTS file (C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc) to map hostnames to the IP address used for your website. That should trick IIS into serving up the correct site based on the hostname you use. The sites would need to be using the same port though, and configured so that they are expecting requests for 'mysite.com' etc.

Regarding SSL, I'm not too sure about that one.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your response. I have already tried using host file to point to different sites on the same machine. In my hosts file I have for example: 10.250.10.11:80  livestaging001
10.250.10.11:8080 livestaging002       I am not able to get that working so that when I type livestaging002 in my browser I should go to the site on the server hosted on port 8080. But I don't know if it is resolving correctly. Is there a way to check?

Comment: I don't think port numbers work in the hosts file, it's purely for mapping hostnames to IP addresses. All of your sites should be able to be served over port 80 as long as they are looking for different hostnames.